# How to implement collision constraints for trajectory optimization in pydrake?

Tags: drake

I'm trying to ensure that a multi-linked robot doesn't collide with an obstacle while doing trajectory optimization. Would I be able to use `ComputeSignedDistancePairClosestPoints` within a `MathematicalProgram` constraint to do this?

For example, if I wanted to add a constraint that my end effector did not collide with a circular geometry, could I add a constraint to all knot points in the trajectory optimization that `ComputeSignedDistancePairClosestPoints` is greater than some distance? My original thought was to use forward kinematics to calculate the end effector position in world coordinates in terms of the state variables (joint angles), then find the distance from this point to the obstacle and add a constraint that the distance must be greater than the radius of the obstacle.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use the constraint [DistanceConstraint](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/56ebd9545d8ae8611a6664c8d2f07a6b3902a11c/multibody/inverse_kinematics/distance_constraint.h#L18) which imposes that the distance between a specific pair of geometries is above certain threshold. Alternatively you can try [MinimumDistanceConstraint](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/56ebd9545d8ae8611a6664c8d2f07a6b3902a11c/multibody/inverse_kinematics/minimum_distance_constraint.h#L71) which says the distance among any pair of geometries is above certain threshold.

In pydrake, you can do

```py
from pydrake.multibody.inverse_kinematics import DistanceConstraint
prog.AddConstraint(DistanceConstraint(plant, [geometry_id1, geometry_id2], plant_context, distance_lower, distance_upper), q)
```

Comment: Do the two geometry IDs need to be part of the same plant? Also what is q?

Comment: Yes, the two geometry IDs need to be part of the same plant? Do you have multiple plant? Usually we have only one plant, but multiple model instances in that plant. You could call model_instance = Parser(plant).AddModelFromFile() to add models to the same plant. The geometry IDs can belong to different model instances.

q is the decision variable representing the generalized position of the whole plant.

Comment: After loading in a urdf of the robot, I'm adding obstacles programmatically with `meshcat.SetObject("obstacle", Cylinder(0.25, 1), Rgba(0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 1))` and then moving the obstacle with the `SetTransform` command. I'm not sure if there is way to use functions you described with this method. I'm also a bit confused if I need to initialize q as a Determinant variable?

Comment: Meshcat is the visualizer, by adding the obstacle to meshcat, the cylindrical obstacle is visualized in meshcat, but the plant and scene_graph (which is used in your trajectory optimization) don't know about this obstacle. In order to add the obstacle to plant, you will need to call scene_graph.RegisterGeometry function (see https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_geometry_instance.html) before calling plant.Finalize().

Comment: In your trajectory optimization program, you probably have declared `q` as decision variables of your program through `q = prog.NewContinuousVariables(nq)`. Now to impose this distance constraint you will call `prog.AddConstraint(DistanceConstraint(...), q)`.